# How to access my own Amazon information without an API, with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, web-scraping

I'm trying to access and store a database of my read books and/or uploaded documents. I don't really mind what the method is as long as it's not scraping the info with some javascript extension in the browser. That defeats my purpose of automation.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Oauth2: Gives me VERY limited information. Email, name, and not much more. So apparently the way is to scrape for that info, so I tried the following:
- [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize): I tried to load the amazon login form and post it with my personal information stored on my server, but it seems this info is not sufficient, not sure why. Some hidden values also needed apparently.
- I tried using an iframe to load the amazon site and the store the session cookies but can't find the way to make this work. Also, is this method allowed? I´m having some concerns about the legitimacy of this.

I know I asked about Amazon I think it also applies to the more general question of how to extract some data from a website that requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) would be a good choice. It uses Selenium to open a browser and navigate to a URL, post form info, etc.